# Running unit tests before building the Angular project in an Azure Pipeline

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Why running unit tests before building the Angular project in an Azure Pipeline is generally a recommended practice?
Also presumably running the tests must include a build.

I have seen at many places people add a step to **Run Unit Test** first and followed by the **Build project** step like below

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% what you're asking here. But you'd run your unit tests in Azure Pipelines to make sure they pass and you're not packaging and potentially deploying known broken code.

Comment: @jessehouwing sorry, added some more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few reasons here:

- building front end app is not the same as building compile code, it means that not necessarily you have to build your for whole app
- when you build front end app you in most case exclude tests from final package (there is no reason to have them deployed, right)
- additionally you also add some additional steps for building your app like minimising code. Imagine how complex it would be actually do read such tests which are minimised (with one exclusion here, quite often for internal environments code is not minimised)
- to execute your test you don't have to build your code, but test runners just transpile code to JavaScript (if you use typescript).